# What does 愛し尽くしたい mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, song-lyrics

This was the [last line](https://vocaloidlyrics.fandom.com/wiki/%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5_(Vanish)) of a song's lyrics. Checking several dictionaries tells me that it means "I want to love ___ to the end", but DeepL is saying something else ("I want to love you all.") and Google Translate is just saying "I want to love you" (where did the 尽くし go?). Which one is correct?

Comment: "I want to love ___ to the end" is most appropriate.

Comment: Don't trust Google Translate to convey any specific nuance.  Machine translation is okay for getting the gist, but not the finer points.

Comment: I want to love to death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means "I want to love all the way to the end", or something like "I want to exhaust my love".

愛し尽くす is made of 愛する(to love) and 尽くす(to exhaust, to complete to the end), and this is a pretty simple combined verb, nothing much to be discussed here.

Also, NEVER trust Google Translate or DeepL fully. You can use them as a reference or to check the meaning of single words(even then it's not reliable), but it should not be considered authoritative at all.

Comment: I think for intermediate learners it's often quite simple to check whether it comes with nonsense or not. Sometimes it comes with something that simply “clicks”. It's not so much blind faith as in helping one see something that one didn't see before. Intermediate learners are also capable of typically feeding it multiple different cases of the same pattern to see whether the answer is consistent.